# reading and writing files for USACO

Tags: c++, c

I am doing code for USACO, but the reading and writing of the files is not working. I am trying to read the first file line and store it as an integer. Subsequent lines will be read and stored into an array to perform calculations. I think the problem has something to do with the fopen. I always get the abort window and it says stream.valid()

Here is the code
_

```
__________________
// USACO MARATHON.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


int main()
{
    FILE *infp;
    FILE *outfp;
    int num_points = 0;
    int x[] = { 0 };
    int y[] = { 0 };
    int total_dist = 0;
    int i;
    infp = fopen("C:\\Users\\jalen\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Project\\real_marathon\\real_marathon\\Debug\\marathon.in", "r");
    outfp = fopen("marathon.out", "w");
    /*if ((infp = fopen("marathon.in", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(infp, "%d", num_points);
    }*/

        num_points = fgetc(infp);

    for (i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        fscanf(infp, "%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);

    }
    for (i = 1; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        int total_distance = abs((x[i] - x[i - 1])) + abs((y[i] - y[i - 1]));
    }
    int max_skip = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < num_points - 1; i++)
    {
        int dont_skip = abs((x[i + 1] - x[i])) + abs((x[i] - x[i - 1])) + abs((y[i + 1] - y[i])) + abs((y[i] - y[i - 1]));
        int skip = abs((x[i + 1] - x[i - 1])) + abs((y[i + 1] - y[i - 1]));
        int z = dont_skip - skip;
        max_skip = z;
    }
    int output = total_dist - max_skip;
    fprintf(outfp, "%d\n", output);
    fclose(infp);
    fclose(outfp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That’s not really (good) C++ code. Don’t dual tag questions. Standard headers should be enclosed in angle brackets (`<>`).

Comment: You might note that `x` and `y` are one element arrays.  Given the C++ tag and `.cpp` extension, you should probably be using `<vector>` and probably a structure instead of a pair of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using ofstream and ifstream:
Where my code says "filename," replace with the name of the file given in the USACO problem statement. `fin` and `fout` are analogous to `cin` and `cout` except that `fin` and `fout` read and print to input/output files.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream fout("filename.out");
ifstream fin("filename.in");

int main()
{
    int N;
    fin >> N;
    fout << N << endl;
}
```